# How to show a hierarchy of fields that make up a whole in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, hierarchy

I am working on a list of material in Tableau that indicates the Level, Part Number, Next Higher Assembly, and Top Level Assembly.  An example of a few rows that I want it to look like is below.  This basically shows that the parts that make up Top1 (level 1) are Mid1 (level 2) and Mid2 (level 2).  Similarly, the parts that make up Mid1 (level 2) are Bot1 (level 3) and Bot2 (level 3).  The part that makes up Mid2 (level 2) is Bot3 (level 3).

What is an easy way to show this hierarchy in Tableau?  It is currently just listing out all of the Level 1's grouped together, all of the Level 2's grouped together, etc.  But I want it to show what other parts actually make up the part.  I assume that the Next Higher Assembly value should be key in helping here.

**What it looks like:**
`LEVEL` `PART #` `NHA`      `TOP LEVEL`
`1`     `Top1`   `Product1` `-`        
 `2`    `Mid1`   `Top1`     `Top1`     
 `2`    `Mid2`   `Top1`     `Top1`     
   `3`  `Bot1`   `Mid1`     `Top1`     
   `3`  `Bot2`   `Mid1`     `Top1`     
   `3`  `Bot3`   `Mid2`     `Top1`

**What I want it to look like:**
`LEVEL` `PART #` `NHA`      `TOP LEVEL`
`1`     `Top1`   `Product1` `-`        
 `2`    `Mid1`   `Top1`     `Top1`     
   `3`  `Bot1`   `Mid1`     `Top1`     
   `3`  `Bot2`   `Mid1`     `Top1`     
 `2`    `Mid2`   `Top1`     `Top1`     
   `3`  `Bot3`   `Mid2`     `Top1`

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field on part # to extract the last digit.

```
right([part #],1)
```

Then place this as the first pill on rows, you may need to set it to a dimension or wrap str() around the calc so it doesn't aggregate it.

Right click on the pill and deselect "Show Header" so the column it hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Bernardo.  The only issue is that all of the Part #'s aren't formatted like that, it's just what I used for the example.  They are all very random numbers but each Part # will always correspond to the same NHA.